# unity - GPU RAM is not released after taking a photo

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to free gpu ram memory after taking a photo 
when reached ~1000 photos my computer is stuck because I used all the gpu ram 
for now I am using the code below to create a photo:

IEnumerator takePhoto(string filename)
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

```
    // Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Save Color Photo");

    Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();

    if(resolution == Resolution.Half)
    {
        screenImage = Utils.Resize(screenImage, Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);
        // screenImage.Apply();
    }

    //Convert to png
    byte[] imageBytes = screenImage.EncodeToPNG();

    //Save image to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename + "_scene.png", imageBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Textur2D` is a Unity Object, which means it will persist beyond script scope (it lives in the Scene).  Either use a singleton-ish pattern so you only need one texture block in memory, or you need to `Destroy` it:

```
    //Save image to file
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename + "_scene.png", imageBytes);

    // Destroy Textur2D Object
    Destroy(screenImage);
}
```

Personally, I'd recommend the singleton-ish pattern:

```
// Create texture as class-level field, outside of function
Texture2D screenImage = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height);

IEnumerator takePhoto(string filename) { yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    // Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Save Color Photo");

    //Get Image from screen
    screenImage.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    screenImage.Apply();
```